# What are the requirements for suggesting a new tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

What are the requirements for suggesting a new tag for Gaming SE via Gaming-Meta versus reputation requirements? As you can see I do not have enough reputation points to create a new tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a new tag is obviously needed and you lack the 300 rep to create it yourself, other users will be happy to add it for you.

Typically, if the tag would apply to a single new question, you can just add a comment on that question asking for someone to create the tag.

If it's a matter of adding a tag to multiple existing questions, I would post the suggestion on meta instead.

Comment: This is what I was looking. However, didn't word the question that way. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 1):

You need 300 reputation. [Read more.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags)